# How to use nested property decorators in Typescript without one overriding the other?

Tags: javascript, typescript, properties, decorator

I am creating my own Typescript decorators for validation, but they are not working together, only the first decorator is activated, the second is ignored. The property `errors` should have a value, because the length passed is less than 3 characters, but is returning undefined.

```
function IsMoreThan(length: number) {
  return (target: any, propertyKey: string) => {
    let val = target[propertyKey];

    const getter = () => val;
    const setter = (value: string) => {
      if (value.length <= length) {
        Object.defineProperty(target, 'errors', {
          value: `${propertyKey} must be more than ${length} characters`,
          configurable: true,
        });
      } else {
        val = value;
      }
    };

    Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
      get: getter,
      set: setter,
      configurable: true,
    });
  };
}

function IsString() {
  return (target: any, propertyKey: string) => {
    let val = target[propertyKey];

    const getter = () => val;
    const setter = (value: string) => {
      const varType = typeof value;
      if (varType !== 'string') {
        Object.defineProperty(target, 'errors', {
          value: `${propertyKey} must be a string, received ${varType}`,
          configurable: true,
        });
      } else {
        val = value;
      }
    };

    Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
      get: getter,
      set: setter,
      configurable: true,
    });
  };
}

class CreateUserSerializer {
  @IsString()
  @IsMoreThan(3)
  public username: string;

  constructor(username: string) {
    this.username = username;
  }
}

const user = new CreateUserSerializer('aa');
console.log(user.errors);
```

Here is a playground with the code for easier testing: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABASQM4Fk4CcCmAVACwEMwAKAGxzAHMoCAuRMEAWwCMcsBKRAbwFgAUIkS4oILElJQiWajiiMSATwA0iAA5Y4GzlGUBpHMsaooWGDR4BeAHx8hIkRASo4lAHTk41UgHk2ACscaA95KD8AdzAABW1dLH0AERxUCAsNKGxpWXD1LR09Q2MuLkcnSihEADcickRrRBk5BQBtAoT9I2UAXQBuIXLnV3ccLx9SWvIuAcEhxBcwM0RwqE4GxFIbeynZpwXXKtQFNawNybqQHFNzS2pth2F9xBhgTamrrypaAkQAHkalBodB4Aiez0QAWCoQAJjhgJYcHFCollDkWlB1AByTjaLCoLHqMEQ-Yfa6IAAGABJeB0it0AL6IFggZYcZnYHBNYhIGlAn5MiDELBEaCcVAU1TzCGLBHUCRENiURjmK5S8HPBkzaWIJk4cjHR4kmp1DZkvaa+YM2bzKEhKAeOEIsBI+JFdF5TRu1HdIk68KMVacdUQ46KRBh04h56ymDykVK8mqnDRkRai3WoQMwaCUCQWAIFCoADKtxoWyNogUEikzQDiBU+W9XWMNwsVga9mJTkWbk83l8dtC4SisWbyhSaQyWSwHoUTZRLeUpUQ80qJvqjTrbTpPuM-Rz+17VSDZ0aFbsG4twyWRxO63PZLbdwe3aPhxNWDwyl0G30ujgN5zR1V53lkb9fwAQmsRosTMdtqCxUEdREIcHSdRFkU6NFt0xRAcSwPECT9DUISfSkaV3JcmRZNkuSICMy2odRcAgHAYGqHAYUQGlai-H8cAZSUUJ7BA5QVRMVSwNURPTHU9QNLk32eKYzUuHBrycbMNUzOYNTQx14Uw8c5zwqjijUSt9nrU9UycMNTHvLA7JvcSE2VJppJTK1tSeXTtKECByCIVBUEQABhXAiDWABVY4sGLTgYDqGAAC91m7AABNBSwQrZymyjBOUIEhSAAZjKJ4NBAJUYAgRBWU4MAiBYcl4LuG0nmPaToGyRrJBatqmOQjU6BgVAPH65rWo2KbBozLMc2PBr4o2F1IgiqLYvixKLBS9LZyxIgiCQ2Ze1GcZfH6jxcWwVBfKAA)

Comment: Well, the outer decorator does not use the property defined by the inner decorator in any way, other than doing `let val = target[propertyKey];` at the beginning. Use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`

Comment: I tried this, but I am still getting the same issue. I don't understand why one decorator interferes in the other

Comment: Your decorators don't "interfere" with each other. The second just completely *overwrites* the result of the first one. Can you [edit] your question to show us how you tried to use `getOwnPropertyDescriptor`?

Comment: Ok, just edited!

Comment: Oh well that's not what I meant. Try `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, propertyKey))` before `let val = …` and I think you'll see where I was going

Comment: Ok, it logs the following `{
  "enumerable": false,
  "configurable": true
} ` in the first decorator, in the second it is `undefined`